# How to create and use a custom `translator` dictionary?

Tags: translator

The following LaTeX code was saved in the file `~/Test.tex`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{translator-test-dictionary-English.dict}
\ProvidesDictionary{translator-test-dictionary}{English}
\providetranslation{phrase}{Hello, world!}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{translator}
\uselanguage{English}
\begin{document}
\translate{phrase}
\end{document}
```

The code creates a file called `translator-test-dictionary-English.dict` in the working directory. The file contains a single key-translation pair with the key `phrase`, and the translation `Hello, world!`. The code then creates an article, loads the `translator` package, and loads all English dictionaries. Finally, the code typesets the translation associated with the key `phrase`.

Then the following commands were executed in the Terminal.

```
> cd ~
> lualatex Test
```

Consequently the file `~/Test.pdf` was generated. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file, which consisted of a single page, displayed the single word: "phrase".

I expected to see the translation "Hello, world!", not the key "phrase". Why wasn't the translation used? How should I change my code so the translation be typeset instead of the key?

Comment: How should translator from your code know that you want to use the test dictionary?  Add `\usedictionary{translator-test-dictionary}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I see. Thanks. Regarding your question: it could have known I wanted the test dictionary because the file name ended with `-English.dict`. I was under the impression (apparently a false impression) that the command `\uselanguage{English}` caused `translator` to load *all* available English dictionaries.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Here's what the `translator` manual says about the `\uselanguage` command: "\uselanguage{<languages> ... This command tells the translator package that it should load the dictionaries for all of the <languages>. The dictionaries are loaded at the beginning of the document." (p. 6 of the current version 2021-05-31)

Comment: Code logic is extremely simple. The manual makes it sound maybe more sophisticated, like an app, instead of 5 or 6 commands. (1) The loop is: for each used-dictionary D, for each used-language L, load the dictionary if the file `D-L.dict` exists.
(2) (a) `\languagepath` is automatically populated with `babel`'s language aliases: so `\translate{phrase}` works; (b) if no `\languagepath` or to override it, use `to=` option: `\translate[to=English]{phrase}`.
(3) English is default language, so `\uselanguage{English}` is not needed.

Comment: @Cicada Step (1) needs to be amended by adding that the file search is case-insensitive. See [the following issue](https://github.com/josephwright/translator/issues/24) which I opened in the `translator` bug tracker a couple hours ago.